# Execute main method inside inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

How to execut main method, if it is present in static inner class?
Main method is present in static inner class and we need to execute that main method.

```
class A {
     static class B {
          public static void main(String[] args) {
             System.out.println("Done");
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  java A$B
```

Update according to comments:

In linux shell you should escape $. So the command became:

`java 'A$B'`

Comment: That won't work if the OP runs this on Linux since shell will try to look up a variable named `B`.

Answer (score 10):

Its just like simple class. Run command `java A$B`
When inner class is compiled, it is prepended with outer class name 
In this case you two class files. i.e . `A.class` and `A$B.class`

- `java` command takes the classname as the argument and not the filename
- So simple command `java A$B` will do the work
- If you have anonymous classes then the classnames will be like `OuterClass$1`, `OuterClass$1` and so on.

So if you modify your example as follows, now including anonymous and method local inner classes

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class A {
    static class B {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Done");
            Serializable obj = new Serializable() {
            };
            Serializable obj1 = new Serializable() {
            };
            class MethodLocalClass {
            }                                           
        }
    }
}
```

Then the class files you will get are `A.class`, `A$B.class`, `A$B$1.class`, `A$B$2.class` for the anonymous classes and `A$B$1MethodLocalClass.class`.

Hope this example helps a bit :)

Answer (score 6):

If your `.java` file have *inner/nested* classes, post compilation those are generated as **TheClass$xxx.class** files by the compiler.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html):

> Inner class definitions produce additional class files. These class
>   files have names combining the inner and outer class names, such as
>   **MyClass$MyInnerClass.class**.

So you should do: `java A$B`.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse go to **Run** -> **Run Configurations** -> then select **Java Application** in the left column -> click the new configuration icon in the top left.

In my case it automatically picked up my inner class with a main method.  This was just a simple example class and I wanted to test it without creating another test/client class.

[image]